# Join de 3 Dataframes

Tags: pandas, join, dataframe, pyspark

necesito un poco de ayuda, necesito unir 3 dataframes en un dataframe nuevo. son dataframes sencillos, donde tienen una columna en comun con el mismo nombre, pero no consigo unir los 3 en un dataframe solo. He probado con Join y con Merge pero no consigo dar con la clave. Podrian ayudarme por favor?

Estos son los 3 dataframes

[image: Estos son los 3 dataframes]

Esta seria la estructura de uno de ellos

[image: Esta seria la estructura de uno de ellos]

Necesito crear un dataframe que sea: EQUIPO,GOLESTOTALES,DISPAROSTOTALES,VICTORIASTOTALES.

Puedo usar Pandas o Pyspark.

He probado con join pero me duplica columnas, he probado con merge pero me dice que una dataframe no puede ser objeto de un merge. En fin, llevo varios dias con esto y no consigo avanzar.
Estoy aprendiendo y estoy usando Databricks.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si asumimos que la columna en común tiene el mismo nombre y los mismos valores exactos, con Pandas, el método a usar es `merge`, el cual debes aplicar de forma encadenada dado que quieres unir más de dos DataFrames, el resto no tiene demasiada ciencia, simplemente especificar que se aplique sobre la columna en común (`EQUIPOS`).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


equipos = ("Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Sociedad", "Valencia", "Betis",
           "Celta", "Ath Madrid", "Villareal", "Girona", "Sevilla", "Eibar",
           "Levante", "Getafe", "Ath Bilbao", "Alaves", "La coruna",
           "Espanol", "Leganes", "Malaga", "Las palmas"
           )

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"EQUIPOS": equipos,
                    "GOLESTOTALES": np.random.randint(24, 99, 20)}
                   )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"EQUIPOS": equipos,
                    "DISPAROSTOTALES": np.random.randint(30, 150, 20)}
                   )

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"EQUIPOS": equipos,
                    "VICTORIASTOTALES": np.random.randint(8, 26, 20)}
                   )
```

> ```
> df_res = (df1.merge(df2, on='EQUIPOS', how='outer')
>              .merge(df3, on='EQUIPOS', how='outer'))
>
> >>> df_res
>
>         EQUIPOS  GOLESTOTALES  DISPAROSTOTALES  VICTORIASTOTALES
> 0     Barcelona            38              127                25
> 1   Real Madrid            75               66                20
> 2      Sociedad            41               35                14
> 3      Valencia            42              129                 9
> 4         Betis            60               81                17
> 5         Celta            91              127                14
> 6    Ath Madrid            60              136                17
> 7     Villareal            35              125                 9
> 8        Girona            90               80                 9
> 9       Sevilla            70               89                24
> 10        Eibar            71              130                24
> 11      Levante            60               49                 8
> 12       Getafe            44               67                15
> 13   Ath Bilbao            28               67                15
> 14       Alaves            92              115                22
> 15    La coruna            48               90                14
> 16      Espanol            73              122                16
> 17      Leganes            55               79                20
> 18       Malaga            32               72                11
> 19   Las palmas            87              123                 8
> ```

Comment: Justo pruebo la solucion que me das pero me marca error.                        
df_res = (df4.merge(df7, on='EQUIPOS', how='outer').merge(df10, on='EQUIPOS', how='outer'))

df_res

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merge'

Comment: FJSevilla muchas gracias, he puesto tu codigo exactamente tal cual, pero he cambiado merge por join y ha funcionado a las mil maravillas ¡ gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda ¡¡